# change NSArray with SegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

help me please. I have 3 `NSArray`: `arr1, arr2, arr3`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {        
     ///arr1
     ///arr2
     ///arr3

     for(NSString *name in arr1) 
     {
        ///mycode 
     }
  }


- (IBAction)didChangeSegmentControl
{
     if (self.switchSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
     {
         NSLog(@"arr1");
     }
     else if (self.switchSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
     {
        NSLog(@"arr2");
     }
     else if (self.switchSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
     {
       NSLog(@"arr3"); 
     }   
}
```

How can I chage this my `arr1` with `arr2` when my `segmentedControl` is `selectedSegmend2`???

I want to change this line `for(NSString *name in arr1)` with `for(NSString *name in arr2)` if `segmentedControl` is `selectedSegment 2`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function like:

```
- (void)checkArray:(NSMutableArray *)yourArray
{
  for(NSString *name in yourArray) 
  {
       //your code 
  }
}
```

And change your method like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {        
     ///arr1
     ///arr2
     ///arr3

     [self checkArray:arr1];
  }


- (IBAction)didChangeSegmentControl
{
     if (self.switchSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
     {
         NSLog(@"arr1");
     }
     else if (self.switchSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
     {
        NSLog(@"arr2");
     }
     else if (self.switchSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
     {
       [self checkArray:arr2];
     }   
}
```